# SQL Query Declaration problem

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a view as shown below.The View is good running.When I attempt to run view,I got the following the error.What might the problem?

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Declare'
```

SQL Query:

```
create View [dbo].StokMaliyet
AS
Declare @Dolar decimal(18,3),@Euro decimal(18,3)

set @Dolar=(select Dolar from GunlukDoviz
set @Euro=(select Euro from GunlukDoviz)

 select Stok_Kodu,
 (case
 when dovtip='3' then net_maliyet
 when dovtip='2' then ((net_maliyet)*@Dolar)/@Euro
 When dovtip='0' then (net_maliyet)/@Euro
 end )  as Maliyet
 from ib_mlyt
```

Comment: Sql Server? What version Sql Server do you use?

Comment: Microsoft SQLServer 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a CTE?

This assumes that you get one row from Dolar and Euro. If you get more then one, add a TOP 1 ..ORDER BY: your original query is wrong too then

```
create View [dbo].StokMaliyet
AS

WITH
    Dolar AS (select Dolar from GunlukDoviz),
    Euro AS (select Euro from GunlukDoviz)
 select Stok_Kodu,
 (case
 when dovtip='3' then net_maliyet
 when dovtip='2' then ((net_maliyet)*Dolar)/Euro 
 When dovtip='0' then (net_maliyet)/Euro
 end )  as Maliyet
 from ib_mlyt
     CROSS JOIN
      Dolar 
     CROSS JOIN
      Euro 
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `declare` and any code manipulation in view (*select statement* ONLY at SQL Server of course).

```
CREATE VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ (column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
[ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ] 
AS select_statement 
[ WITH CHECK OPTION ] [ ; ]

<view_attribute> ::= 
{
    [ ENCRYPTION ]
    [ SCHEMABINDING ]
    [ VIEW_METADATA ]     }
```

See [for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Use [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) instead of view

Comment: +1 as you have the been the only one to note that **you cannot use DECLARE** inside a view

Comment: @Andrew Bickerton yes of course, because Cell-o could not describe all own code. If he did, I will applaud to gbn's and Simon's solutions (if its work). :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change it to

```
create View [dbo].StokMaliyet
AS
 select Stok_Kodu,
 (case
 when dovtip='3' then net_maliyet
 when dovtip='2' then ((net_maliyet)*(select top (1) Dolar from GunlukDoviz))/(select top (1) Euro from GunlukDoviz)
 When dovtip='0' then (net_maliyet)/(select top (1) Euro from GunlukDoviz)
 end )  as Maliyet
 from ib_mlyt
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can do Cartesian product using `CTE` as our `CTE` would be only one row .

```
create View [dbo].StokMaliyet
AS
WITH
    CTEDolar AS (select top 1 cast (Dolar  as decimal(8,7) )Dolar from GunlukDoviz),
    CTEEuro AS (select top 1 cast (Euro  as decimal(8,7) ) Euro  from GunlukDoviz)
 select Stok_Kodu,
 (case
 **strong text**when dovtip='3' then net_maliyet
 when dovtip='2' then ((net_maliyet)*Dolar)/Euro 
 When dovtip='0' then (net_maliyet)/Euro
 end )  as Maliyet
 from ib_mlyt,CTEDolar as CTEDolar ,CTEEuro as CTEEuro

GO
```